# Use MSAL without bundle_id configured on Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

My iOS app has to address an application on an Azure AD server, upon which I don't have admin access. I know the `client_id`, `tenant_id` and `redirect_uri` (Azure AD application).

My iOS app's `bundle_id` is not registered for the required application (`msauth.[bundle_id]://auth`)

**Aim:** Get the **bearer token** in order to access the application directly from my iOS app.

That's the MSAL config:

```
let kClientID = [client_id]
let kGraphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
let kAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant_id]"
let kRedirectUri = [redirect_uri]
let kScopes: [String] = ["user.read"]
```

**Question:** Is it an absolute requirement that the `bundle_id` is registered in Azure AD for a specific application, or are there other means getting the bearer token using MSAL, knowing `client_id`, `tenant_id` and `redirect_uri`?